# List formatting is broken: neither bulleted nor numbered lists render in posts

Tags: bug, status-completed, markdown-rendering, formatting

I tried using `-` to add bullets, but it's not working.

e.g.

- line1
- line2
- line3

I wrote it as such:

```
 - line1
 - line2
 - line3
```

It's also missing from my previous posts. e.g. see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42275060/what-is-difference-between-remote-notification-and-silent-notification-in-ios/42302369#42302369)

This affects both bulleted lists (`-` and `*`) and numbered lists.

Comment: Oh, dear.  Apparently the bug [has occurred system-wide](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/337284/102937).

Comment: Can confirm I also noticed this happening.

Comment: It looks fine for me but I’m on the app :p

Comment: Will we have to refresh the page to see the fix? Am in the middle of writing a long answer

Comment: Working fine now on this page. And on the page you linked to.

Comment: Works for me also - props to the devs' promptness.

Answer (score 5):

It's fixed now. For more, see [the answer on the global Meta from developer Dean Ward](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/337289):

> Apologies for this, a bunch of CSS was removed because it was supposed to be dead. Turns out it wasn't; we've put back the things that were removed and things are back to normality.